# Hibernate Error: Unable to convert between net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime and BINARY

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I am getting the following error and I am not sure how to resolve it. Any inofrmation would be appreciated.

I am trying to copy data from a MSSQL database to MySQL database using Quartz to schedule the job and Hibernate as my ORM.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.DateTime and BINARY.

MySQL Column:
    `LASTMODIFIEDDATE` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL

MSSQL Column:
    [LASTMODIFIEDDATE] [datetime] NULL,

Hibernate Method:
    public List findLastUpdatedCases() {
        final String ModRestriction = "DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(datetime,LASTMODIFIEDDATE, 110),Getdate())=0";

```
List<CaseViewGtWy> caseList = getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(
    new HibernateCallback() {
                public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

                    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(getPersistentClass());
                    criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction((ModRestriction)));

                    return criteria.list();
                }
            }
    );
    return caseList;
}
```

Comment: Properties are being copied with BeanUtils.copyProperties(Case, gtwyCase); though a Quartz job.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was an error (a class mismatch) in my Hibernate DAO. Resolved that and things seem to be working.